# Lower() vs ilike on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, orm

What I want to do is to check if value of column equals some string, but case insensitive. Is there a performance difference when using `ilike` without wildcards (percents) and `lower()` ?

I was planning to create index on `lower(column_name)` and use `lower(column_name) = value` (value is lower case already) but it turns out that ORM I'm using doesn't allow me to use `lower()` in a pretty way (but has convenient method for `ilike`). Will `column_name ilike 'value'` use `lower(column_name)` index?

Answer (score 4):

Measure it and see, using `explain analyze` on test data.

I would expect a significant difference between an expression index on `lower(col)` with `lower(col) = lower('constant')` vs use of `col ilike 'constant'`, with the expression index on `lower(col)` the faster.

That's because Pg can do a bitmap index scan with the expression index, but for the `ilike` it'll have to do a seqscan. AFAIK a `text_pattern_ops` index (useful for `LIKE`) won't do you any good for `ILIKE`.

The other question is whether the difference is worth caring about, and that depends on your data and workload. Sometimes it's smarter to just choose the slower but easier option and spend yourtime/effort elsewhere.

> Will column_name ilike 'value' use lower(column_name) index?

No. Nor will it use an index on `lower(column_name) text_pattern_ops`. AFAIK there is no way to index a case-insensitive pattern match (`ILIKE` or `~~*`) on a case-sensitive text/varchar in PostgreSQL at this time.

I don't think [the `citext` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html) changes this, though it does make things more convenient.

Comment: "*AFAIK there is no way to index a case-insensitive pattern match at this time*" - http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/ and http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/212-PostgreSQL-9.1-Trigrams-teaching-LIKE-and-ILIKE-new-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

If you build an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_indexname
ON yourtable (LOWER(columnname) ASC NULLS LAST);
```

Lower will use index.

ILIKE will use index, but only in some case. I suggest starting here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-types.html

Comment: _It is also possible to use B-tree indexes for ILIKE and ~*, but only if the pattern starts with non-alphabetic characters, i.e., characters that are not affected by upper/lower case conversion._